# Web Service that returns different URLs

Tags: web-services, telerik-reporting

I am currently creating a Web Service where in the user will input 3 parameters namely ReportID, Username and RecipeXML. The RecipeXML is the URL of the XML file that will serve as the data source of the Telerik Report that I am doing. I have successfully connected the XML data source to my Telerik Report, now I want to ask how can my Web Service return different URLs every time the user or client generate a report? For example, user1 generated a report right now the Web Service will return a URL something like "report.com/report001" after a while user2 generated another report and the 
Web Service will return something like “report.com/report002” and so on. Please someone tell me how can you do this?
Additional information, the report viewer (where the report can be previewed) is located on my ViewReport.aspx file. Also, as of now the URL that my Web Service is returning is something like `“http://localhost:51744/Views/Home/ViewReport.aspx”` since I am not yet  deploying my Web Service on the web. 
My environment is VB.Net, .Net Framework 4, Visual Studio 2012, Telerik Reporing (as Reporting Tool)